# create EAR file in Jdeveloper

Tags: java, soa, jdeveloper, bpel

I have created a SOA project in JDeveloper. not I want to create a EAR file for deploying the project in Developement.

I tried by creating deployment profile, but ear option always disable for this.

and when i create simple j2ee project, then I can create ear for project.

please tell me how can I generate ear file from Jdeveloper.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that you meant a SOA project to be a SOA Composite project, you'll need to be aware of the fact that SOA Composites are not deployed in the form of EAR files. Instead, SAR (SOA archives) files are created and provided for deployment.

Details on how to create and deploy SAR files from JDeveloper can be found in the [Oracle FMW Guide for SOA Suite](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E12839_01/integration.1111/e10224/sca_lifecycle.htm).

Comment: Thanks for the answer,but it will generate a jar file, so how we will deploy jar file on server, administration guys telling us jar file we can deploy as library only.. can u help me in that...

Comment: @Abhishek, I dont think they are aware of SOA archives; they might be referring to WLS libraries. Refer to Chapter 5 of the [FMW Administrator's Guide](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E12839_01/integration.1111/e10226/toc.htm), if you cannot deploy from JDeveloper, but have to do so from the Administration Console.

Comment: Thanks Vineet really you helped me.